# A Data Recovery proof on K-means algorithm objective function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, solution-verification, machine-learning, data-analysis

There are quite a few materials about the K-means algorithm,
but what I need is proof of how its objective function is derived based on the so-called data recovery approach.
Ref. for this approach: B. Mirkin, Clustering: A Data Recovery Approach, CRC Press (1st Edition, 2005; 2d Edition, 2012). The book can be downloaded freely:
[http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~mirkin/papers/n.pdf](http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/%7Emirkin/papers/n.pdf)

**My question:**

Given an entity-to-feature matrix $Y = (y_{iv}) \in \mathbb R^{N}$ and given number of clusters K. The goal is to cluster Y into K disjoint sets, that is, $S = \{S_1, S_2, ...., S_K \}$. And the cluster $S_{k}$ is represented by a $N \times 1$ column vector $s_{k} = (s_{ik})$, where $s_{ik}=1$ if $i \in S_{k}$ and  $s_{ik}=0$, otherwise ($i\in I$).

To related the notion of members of the clusters having similar feature values, we consider the standard $V$-dimensional point of $S_{k}$, $c_{k}=(c_{k v})$ ($v=1, ..., V, k=1, ..., K$).

Then, as it is described on page 288:

\begin{equation}
\label{e1}
y_{iv} = c_{kv} + e_{iv}; \  i \in S_{k}   \ \ \ (7.18)
\end{equation}

As the author wrote:
multiplying equations (7.18) by themselves and summing up the results,
it is not difficult to derive the following equation:

\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:y_iv_sqr_sum}
\sum_{i,v} y_{iv}^{2} =  \sum_{k=1}^{K} \sum_{v} c_{kv}^{2} |S_{k}| +  \sum_{i,v} e_{iv}^{2}  \ \ \ \ (7.19)
\end{equation}

Now my question is whether the textbook's proof is correct or not?
Because I obtain something which slightly differs from it, I have the coefficient $K$ multiplied with the LHS and last term of RHS.

**Here is my proof**

defining the model as:

\begin{equation}
\label{e:2}
y_{iv} = c_{kv} s_{ik} + e_{iv} \ \ (i=1, ..., N, v \in V, k=1, ..., K)
\end{equation}

Rearranging, squaring and summing over all clusters, all data points and all features implies:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{K} \sum_{i,v} e_{i v}^{2} = \sum_{k=1}^{K} \sum_{i, v}(y_{i v} - c_{k v} s_{i k})^{2}
\end{equation}

Furthermore, we have:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
K \sum_{i,v} e_{i v}^{2} = \sum_{k=1}^{K} \sum_{i, v} (y_{i v}^{2} - 2 y_{iv} c_{k v} s_{i k} + c_{k v}^{2} s_{i k}^{2})
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Recalling the definition of the mean:

\begin{equation}
    c_{k v} = \frac{\sum_{i} y_{iv} s_{ik}}{|S_{k}|}=\frac{\sum_{i\in S_{k}}y_{iv}}{|S_{k}|}
    \label{eqn:def_ck_same_mdl}
\end{equation}

And by substituting it in its above-mentioned Eqn. and little algebric manipulation we will obtain:

\begin{equation}
      K \sum_{i,v} y_{iv}^{2} =  \sum_{k=1}^{K} \sum_{ v} c_{kv}^{2} |S_{k}| + K \sum_{i,v} e_{iv}^{2}  \ \ \ \ (*)
\end{equation}

The above Eqn. holds because:

1. $\sum_{i} s_{ik}^2 = \sum_{i} s_{ik} = |S_{k}|$ since $s_k$ is a N-dimensional binary vector;
2. for a given $k$ recalling the definition of the mean, $ c_{k v} = \frac {1}{|S_{k}|} \sum_{i \in S_{k}} y_{i v} $, we find $\sum_{v} c_{k v} \sum_{i \in S_{k}} y_{i v}= \sum_{v} c_{k v} c_{k v} |S_{k}| = |S_{k}| \sum_{v} c_{k v}^2$.

Am I right?
(Because in the book there is no such a $K$ as I obtained Eqn. (*))

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending several hours I finally managed to prove it properly so that it is compatible with the proof in the textbook.  (Although I will not close this question  for a while so that probably someone wants to provide another answer)

Here is my proof:

Since we have $K$ non-overlapping clusters therefore, we can define our model as:

\begin{equation}
\label{model_f}
y_{iv} = \sum_{k=1}^{K} c_{kv}s_{ik} + e_{iv},
\end{equation}

Rearranging and squaring implies:

\begin{equation}
\label{model_f_sqr}
e_{iv}^2 =  (y_{iv} - \sum_{k=1}^{K} c_{kv}s_{ik})^2,
\end{equation}

opening the parenthesis yields:

\begin{equation}
\label{model_f_sqr_opn}
e_{iv}^2 =  y_{iv}^2 - 2 y_{iv} \sum_{k=1}^{K} c_{kv}s_{ik} + \sum_{k=1}^{K} c_{kv}^2 s_{ik}^2,
\end{equation}

By summing over all entities, all features and, rearranging a bit:

\begin{equation}
\label{model_f_sqr_opn_sums}
\sum_{i,v} e_{iv}^2 =  \sum_{i,v} y_{iv}^2 - 2 \sum_{i,v} \sum_{k=1}^{K} y_{iv} s_{ik} c_{kv} + \sum_{i,v} \sum_{k=1}^{K} c_{kv}^2 s_{ik}^2.
\end{equation}

Now we should recall two facts:

1. definition of the average of a cluster, $k$ over a feature, $v$:
   $c_{kv} = \frac{\sum_{i}y_{iv}s_{ik}}{N_{k}}$. Where $N_{k}$ is the cluster cardinality. Therefore we have $\sum_{i}y_{iv}s_{ik} = c_{kv} N_{k}$
2. Since the cluster membership vectors ($s_{k}$) are binary, thus: $\sum_{i} s_{ik}^2 = \sum_{i} s_{ik} = N_{k}$

Therefore,

w.r.t 1) $ -2 \sum_{i,v} \sum_{k=1}^{K} y_{iv} s_{ik} c_{kv} = \sum_{k} \sum_{v} c_{kv}^{2} N_{k}$;

And

w.r.t 2) $ \sum_{k=1}^{K} \sum_{v} \sum_{i} c_{kv}^2 s_{ik}^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{K} \sum_{v} c_{kv}^2 N_{k}$

Therefore, we have:

\begin{equation}
\label{model_proof}
\sum_{i,v} e_{iv}^2 =  \sum_{i,v} y_{iv}^2 - \sum_{k=1}^{K} \sum_{v} c_{kv}^2 N_{k} 
\end{equation}

And the proof is complete.